# How can I stop a stainless steel drinking water tank from leaking?

Tags: water, leak, water-tank

I have stainless steel drinking water tank that is leaking from the weldings (few pin holes).

What is the best way to stop these leaks, without draining the tank? 
Welding could be option but I have no access to it.

Does some kind of adhesive exist that could be applied to wet surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a product called "Sealsall". You can get it at any hardware store.  This stuff is easy to use, Dry the seam as best as you can, then just apply some to the leaking seam before it gets too wet again. Try not to get it on your fingers as it will take a week to get it off!!  Sealsall dries clear and should be good for years.  I have used it on everything from a canoe bottom, car gas tank, to hot tubs with success.  Good Luck

Comment: Hi. Is [this](http://eclecticproducts.com/sealall.htm) the stuff you have in mind? I'm in India, and have a similar problem.

Comment: @shirlockhomes Can you answer [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/67540/33)?

Comment: Is the brand you're talking about [Seal-All](http://eclecticproducts.com/seal-all.html)?

Answer (score 1):

JBweld's WaterWeld epoxy works wet, and can be used for potable water tanks. http://www.jbweld.com/products/waterweld-epoxy-putty