# Is SealsAll still available?

Tags: adhesive, sealant

I read [an answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8534/how-can-i-stop-a-stainless-steel-drinking-water-tank-from-leaking/8535#8535) which referred to a product called "SealsAll", but I can't find this product. Anyone know if it still available?

Thanks Tester101.
That does look like a more appropriate product for the tank leak. 
However I was interested in the floor/deck sealer called SealsAll. 
I have found mention of it online, and the manufacturer being Seal America Inc., but I can't find any further info on the company or product. 
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm confused... You read about a product in a question about how to seal a leak in a metal tank, but thought the product would be appropriate for sealing floors/decking?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect @shirlockhomes may have been referring to [Seal-All®](http://eclecticproducts.com/seal-all.html). Though it's impossible to say for sure, as I'm not @shirlockhomes.

[image: Seal-All]